# Why can't I see my object when I switch to object mode?

Tags: modeling, 3d-view

I have work in my project from the edit mode and after I am done ، when i want to go to object mode i can't see the the model i have work on it ... what is the problem !?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try press Alt + H in Object Mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the *Mask Modifier*. The *Mask Modifier* essentially hides the mesh apart for the parts that can be set using a *Vertex Group* which is done in *Weight Paint Mode*. This is very helpful when working with a very complex mesh.